# How to access vertices via edge list iteration igraph R

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, vertex, edge-list

I am trying to access the vertices of each vertex pair in an edge using a for loop like this:

```
for (e in E(G)) { do stuff }
```

However, I don't know how to get each vertex in `e`.  I am trying to return the type of each vertex, which is in the vertex list.  I can get the vertex attribute like I do below, though I am not sure if this is an ok way to iterate through the edge list and get all the edges:

```
i = 1

for (e in get.edgelist(G)) {
    if(V(G)[get.edgelist(G)[i,][1]]$type %in% vector &&
       V(G)[get.edgelist(G)[i,][2]]$type %in% vector ) { do stuff }
    i = i + 1
}
```

I also noticed that `e in E(G)` returns an index, so is it correct to do it like this?

```
for (e in E(G)) {
    if(V(G)[get.edgelist(G)[e,][1]]$type %in% vector &&
       V(G)[get.edgelist(G)[e,][2]]$type %in% vector ) { do stuff }
}
```

I believe the last example does what I want, but I am not sure of the mechanics of iGraph to be sure I am indexing the edges correctly.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up edge frequencies this appears to work:

```
for (e in E(G)) {
 if(V(G)[get.edgelist(G)[e,][1]]$type %in% vector &&
  V(G)[get.edgelist(G)[e,][2]]$type %in% vector ) { do stuff }
}
```